# How do I inspect http request and response manually in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, http

I'm developing and application for iPhone - with OAuth part and following couple requests and responses.

I need to inspect manually what is being sent to server (in request header and body) and what is being sent back in response (response header and body).

Are there any soft tools?
Or is there any possibility to print request/response content from code to console?

I'm using OS X 10.11.1 El Capitan, Xcode 7.0.1, iOS Simulator with iOS 9.0 (no real device yet)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/).

It's a proxy you install on your desktop, and after configuring your device to work with it you can inspect all http/https traffic.

Comment: can it show the detailed request and response, like in firebug?

Comment: e.g. this way

HTTP/1.1 302 Found

Date: Tue, 10 Nov 2015 14:53:54 GMT

Server: Apache/2.2.24

Location: http://feed.meltwater.com/gyda/outputs/xml/html/21/10/125053.html

Content-Length: 327

Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100

Connection: Keep-Alive

Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Comment: I don't know what firebug is, but it shows everything you need - url, headers, body...

Comment: Yes, and it also formats all that.
It also has built in support for Python scripts and allows you to intercept/edit requests.

Comment: firebug is a plugin for firefox browser.